# UIL: load image from external storage

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

Hi im trying to load image from the native OS gallery using UIL and the following uri:

```
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140713_103602.jpg
```

And im getting:

```
UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140713_103602.jpg]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: UIL doesn't support scheme(protocol) by default [/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140713_103602.jpg]. You should implement this support yourself (BaseImageDownloader.getStreamFromOtherSource(...))
```

Any suggestion how can i load such an image?

Comment: See it here : [Android - Better Approach in Loading SD CARD Images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17420664/android-better-approach-in-loading-sd-card-images)

Answer (score 4):

In UIL if you are loading image from SDCARD you should use prefix **file:///** as

```
  String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png"; // from SD card
```

i.e.

```
 "file:///"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()
                + File.separator + "image.png";
```

So use image path as

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140713_103602.jpg
```

Comment: Already tried it, getting: 
 Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140713_103602.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-21 09:55:15.850  22038-22662/com.autodesk.autocad360.cad.staging D/Sean9﹕ getCurrentHub, mCurrentHub null? false

Comment: @EvgeniRoitburg Did you add permission "    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
"

Comment: @EvgeniRoitburg try to append "file:///" not "file:/"

Comment: Im sending  "file:///+ path" the i assume it changed somehow when printed to logs

Comment: @EvgeniRoitburg try to send full path like "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140713_103602.jpg"

Answer (score -1):

Try the below format,

```
String imageUri = "file:///mnt/sdcard/image.png"; // from SD card
```