# Recursion making explorer slow

Tags: android, recursion

This code to check mp3 songs (using recursion)is making my explorer very slow 
please suggest me a way to make it faster

```
public static boolean getMp3s1(File dir){
            int h=0;
             File[] listFile = dir.listFiles();
             if(listFile!=null)
             for( int i=0; i< listFile.length; i++)
             {
                 if(listFile[i].isDirectory()==true)
                 getMp3s1(listFile[i]);
                 else
                 {
                     if(listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".mp3")==true||listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".MP3")==true)
                         h=1;
            }

          }
         if(h==1){
             h=0;
             return true;
        }
         else
             return false;

        }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530921/list-all-the-files-from-all-the-folder-in-a-single-list. Hope this will help you.

Comment: Whenever a method is called it puts all the code ahead of the call into a stack bring code inside the function to execution and after completion bring original code out of stack and into execution. This happens over and over again in recursion and multiple stacks are created the higher the number of calls the slower the program becomes Thus you could do the same in a infinite for loop which exits only on a break and still be more efficient

Comment: @PraveenKumar Bro i asked to resolve recursion .the code u mentioned is to get all fies and folders.........my code is to check whether a folder and its subfolders contains mp3 file or not .thats why i need to use recursion and that made my application slow.........still thanks a lot to reply

Comment: @WisdmLabs can u give any example of implementing this by for loop .as i cannt do this by for loop...

Comment: You could try something like this but its in java so you would have to make some changes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3154488/best-way-to-iterate-through-a-directory-in-java

Answer (score 1):

try to break your loop after h=1; it can speed up a little.
like this bellow:

```
public static boolean getMp3s1(File dir){
        int h=0;
         File[] listFile = dir.listFiles();
         if(listFile!=null)
         for( int i=0; i< listFile.length; i++)
         {
             if(listFile[i].isDirectory()==true)
             getMp3s1(listFile[i]);
             else
             {
                 if(listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".mp3")==true||listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".MP3")==true)
                    {
                      h=1;
                     break;
                    }
        }

      }
     if(h==1){
         h=0;
         return true;
    }
     else
         return false;

    }
```

EDIT:
as i see from your code logic it seems that you can skip getMp3s1(listFile[i]); too.

Comment: yeah u r rite :).but it is still slow..and sorry i cannt upvote ur answer as my repo is less than 15 :(