# how to get total size of all photos/videos/musics in android?

Tags: android, image, video, android-file

I'm new to android, I'm creating an application which shows the complete summary of android device,
I need the total size used by Images/Videos/Musics which resides anywhere in android system. How do I do?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8133437/3061577

There you can find a pretty good overview of finding the usage of internal and external memory.

For getting specified data about the usage of photos, music and videos you'll need to do a bit of more work. First you need to find all files and then filter out the right files with the right file extension.

A detailed exmaple here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9531063/3061577