# How to get all the audio file using mediastore

Tags: java, android, file, mediastore

I am trying to get all the media files from the device (Internal and SDcard).Till now I am able to get all the media files from a fixed folder of SD Card .I have gone through most of the web pages on mediastore .And i am able to get the media info.But how can I get all the audio files from the device any example  will be helpful.
I tried this way ` public class SongDto {

```
public long songId;
public String songTitle;
public String songArtist;
public String path;
public short genre;
public long duration;
public String album;
public Bitmap albumArt;

public String toString() {
return String.format("songId: %d, Title: %s, Artist: %s, Path: %s, Genere: %d, Duration %s",
        songId, songTitle, songArtist, path, genre, duration);
}
```

and getting these value in another class name

```
public class Utils {
private Context _context;

// constructor
public Utils(Context context) {
    this._context = context;
}
public static ArrayList<SongDto> getMusicInfos(Context context) {

    ArrayList<SongDto> musicInfos = new ArrayList<SongDto>();
```

and now I am trying to get the the songTitle in another class

```
private ArrayList<SongDto> musicInfos;
private Utils utils;
private ArrayList<String> songPaths = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    utils = new Utils(this);
    songPaths = utils. getMusicInfos(songTitle);
}

private void update(){
    ArrayAdapter<String> list=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,musicInfos.add(songTitle) );
}
}
```

How I can get only the desired array like array of songId ,songArtist,song duration.And where I am doing wrong .How to set the getMusicInfos method
`

Comment: You can get the all folders of the sd card and than make the check that any folder containing the your media file, if it is containing your file than add it into yours temporary ARRAYLIST... Try these and let me know in case of concern... http://stackoverflow.com/a/9531063/3946958

Comment: I want to get the audio file from both internal and external storage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
 ArrayList audio=new ArrayList();
 Cursor c=getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);


while(c.moveToNext())
 {
String name=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
audio.add(name);

 }
```

and similarly you can also get the internel storage audio files by specifying INTERNEL_CONTENT_URI

Answer (score 2):

I used this code to get all song data

```
public static ArrayList<SongDto> getMusicInfos(Context context) {

    ArrayList<SongDto> musicInfos = new ArrayList<SongDto>();

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        cursor.moveToNext();


        int isMusic = cursor.getInt(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC)); 

        if (isMusic != 0) {
            SongDto music = new SongDto();


            music.path = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA));

            if (!new File(music.path).exists()) {
                continue;
            }


            music.songId = cursor.getLong(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID));

            music.songTitle = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE));


            music.songTitle = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));


            music.album = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM));


            music.songArtist = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST));

            music.duration = cursor
                    .getLong(cursor
                            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION));

            MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mmr.setDataSource(music.path);
            music.albumArt = getBitmap(mmr.getEmbeddedPicture());
            mmr.release();

            musicInfos.add(music);
        }
    }

    return musicInfos;
}
```

and use this as data object

```
public class SongDto {

public long songId;
public String songTitle;
public String songArtist;
public String path;
public short genre;
public long duration;
public String album;
public Bitmap albumArt;

public String toString() {
    return String.format("songId: %d, Title: %s, Artist: %s, Path: %s, Genere: %d, Duration %s",
            songId, songTitle, songArtist, path, genre, duration);
}
}
```

AbumArt might come as null

To fetch song id as list

```
 String[] columns = { MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID };
    cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,columns, null, null, null);
```

and get the data from cursor. To get both internal and external storage songs list, as of now I don't have a solution.

Comment: so I have to set array list twice to get the external and internal song  ?

Comment: and how I can get the given info like sondId in a array

Answer (score 0):

The following code fetches all the mp3 files in the phone (including the audio files downloaded from messangers, recorded files etc) :

```
private fun getAllMusics(): List<String> {
    val result = mutableListOf<String>()

    val cursor = contentResolver.query(
        MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external"),
        arrayOf(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA),
        "${MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE} = ?",
        arrayOf(MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("mp3")),
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED
    )

    cursor?.let {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                result.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA)) ?: "--")
            }
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

You can get other audio files (like WAV, WMA etc) by modifying the `selection` and `selection args` parameters.