# How to get currently plaing audio file info in background (The audio may be playing by any app) in android

Tags: android, audio, service

I'm going to make one app, in this the partial requirement is like this: get the currently playing audio name using service. I tried but I'm unable to find the exact way, here is my finding. [How to get all the audio file using mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495822/how-to-get-all-the-audio-file-using-mediastore)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to know what file another app may be playing.