# I want to load not only MP3 files but also othe music file format how can I do this?

Tags: android

my problem is that I want to load all music file format but also I have created music list but when am run app it do not show the music list from the internal storage the following are the codes

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    private  static final String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };
    //request  permission
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSION = 12345;
    //store counted permission
    private static final  int PERMISSION_COUNT = 1;
    //check for permission asked
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private  boolean arePermissionDenied(){
        for (int i =0; i < PERMISSION_COUNT; i++){
            //check if permission granted
            if (checkSelfPermission(PERMISSIONS[i])!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    //get the result of the permission
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[]grantResults){
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        //if permission denied close the app
        if (arePermissionDenied()){
            ((ActivityManager) (this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE))).clearApplicationUserData();
            recreate();
        }
        else{
            onResume();
        }
    }

    //initializing music player
    private boolean isMusicPlayerInit;
    //create variable to store music file
    private List<String> musicFilesList;

    //add music from the directory
    private void addMusicFrom(String dirPath){
        final File musicDir = new File(dirPath);
        if (!musicDir.exists()){
            musicDir.mkdir();
        return;
        }
        final File[] files = musicDir.listFiles();
        for (File file : files){
            final String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
            if (path.endsWith(".mp3")){
                musicFilesList.add(path);
            }
        }
    }

    private void fillMusicList(){
        musicFilesList.clear();
        addMusicFrom(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)));
        addMusicFrom(String.valueOf(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)));

    }
    private  void playMusicFiles(String path){
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();

        try {
            mp.setDataSource(path);
            mp.prepare();
            mp.start();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void  onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && arePermissionDenied()){
            requestPermissions(PERMISSIONS, REQUEST_PERMISSION);
            return;
        }
        if (!isMusicPlayerInit){
            final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
            final TextAdapter textAdapter = new TextAdapter();
            musicFilesList = new ArrayList<>();
            fillMusicList();
            textAdapter.setData(musicFilesList);
            listView.setAdapter(textAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    final  String musicFilePath = musicFilesList.get(position);
                    playMusicFiles(musicFilePath);
                }
            });

            isMusicPlayerInit = true;
        }
    }
    //create list to hold data
    class TextAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
        private List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

        void setData(List<String> mData){
            data.clear();
            data.addAll(mData);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount(){
            return data.size();

        }
        @Override
        public String getItem(int position){
            return null;

        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position){
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            if (convertView == null){
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
                convertView.setTag(new ViewHolder((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.myItem)) );
            }
            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            final String item = data.get(position);
            holder.info.setText(item.substring((item.lastIndexOf('/')+1)));
            return convertView;
        }
        class  ViewHolder{
            TextView info;

            ViewHolder(TextView mInfo){
                info = mInfo;
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I need how to do that when am open this app no any music is shown from the device
and that means no music loaded so how do I load the music from the device
all prerequisites like permission I had provided them

Comment: As per Google's new privacy policy updates for Android Q and above you should use MediaStore for that and you might be looking for something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37495926/6791222

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all the audio file using mediastore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495822/how-to-get-all-the-audio-file-using-mediastore)