# Get all files in all folders in internal and external storage

Tags: android

I'm working on a project on android studio and I need help.. How can I search for a file by its name in all folders in internal and external storage??

I tried using for loop to search in internal.. And I tested if the file doesn't exist , the path will be the old path+the folder name. It didn't work out

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: what are you trying to do please elaborate, the question should be complete and clear with what you already tried and where you stuck

Comment: try this [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9530921/list-all-the-files-from-all-the-folder-in-a-single-list)

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void getAllDir(File dir) {
        String pdfPattern = ".pdf or .txt or .jpg etc..";

        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    getAllDir(listFile[i]);
                } else {
                  if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(pdfPattern)){
                                      //Do what ever u want

                  }
                }
            }
        }    
    }


and call this function like

getAllDir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
```